# How to extract text from such type of html source?

Tags: html, delphi, parsing

I have html source containing about 1000 microblogs (one tweet per line). Most of the tweets are like the below. I am using delphi memo to try to strip html marks by using Pos function and delete function but failed.

```
<div id='tweetText'> RT <a onmousedown="return touch(this.href,0)" href="http://twitter.com/HighfashionUK">@HighfashionUK</a> RT: Surprise goody bag up 4 grabs, Ok. <a onmousedown="return touch(this.href,0)" href="http://plixi.com/p/57846587">http://plixi.com/p/57846587</a> when we get 150</div>
```

I want to strip html marks and only have:

```
RT: Surprise goody bag up 4 grabs, Ok. http://plixi.com/p/57846587 when we get 150
```

How can I extract such text in delphi?

Thank you very much in advance.

**Update:**

Cosmin Prund is right. I mistakenly skipped a part. What I want is :

```
RT @HighfashionUK  RT: Surprise goody bag up 4 grabs, Ok. http://plixi.com/p/57846587 when we get 150
```

Cosmin Prund is great.

Comment: Are you sure you can't just use the Twitter API?

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract? You seem to only want text (ie: ignore all tags), but you skipped the inner-text of the first anchor tag (@HighfashionUK). Was that intentional or a mistake?

Comment: Before closing for `dupe`: It's not a dupe if the OP wants to remove all HTML markup and only keep text. You don't need to parse HTML in order to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since all HTML markup is between `<` and `>`, a routine to strip markup can be trivially written like this. Hopefully this is what you want because, as you see in my comment, there's a issue with `@HighfashionUK` - your example skipped that, don't know why.

```
function StripHtmlMarkup(const source:string):string;
var i, count: Integer;
    InTag: Boolean;
    P: PChar;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(source));
  P := PChar(Result);
  InTag := False;
  count := 0;
  for i:=1 to Length(source) do
    if InTag then
      begin
        if source[i] = '>' then InTag := False;
      end
    else
      if source[i] = '<' then InTag := True
      else
        begin
          P[count] := source[i];
          Inc(count);
        end;
  SetLength(Result, count);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. See my update. but why you say "You don't need to parse HTML in order to do that". Are there other methods to do that?

Comment: are there html parsers (library/component) for delphi?

Comment: @Warren, an HTML parser would normally read *and understand* all HTML markup, producing an document tree, or a DOM (Document Object Model). You can traverse the tree and extract all text, but once you have a DOM you can also do smarter things, like extracting the "href" of anchors, or ignoring certain tags. My method doesn't have any HTML-specific knowledge, all it knows is that tags start with `<` and end with `>` and it's supposed to ignore everything between the markers. It's fast and effective, but less powerful then a full DOM parser.

Comment: @Warren, I'm sure there are Delphi HTML parsers, and I'm also sure you can use non-Delphi specific parsers (example: you can load your HTML into an TWebBrowser and then use it's DOM) but I can't recommend any because I never used one. I did parse my share of HTML, but my "parsers" were hand-made and targeted to a specific web page.

Comment: Besides removing text inside <..>, you will need to remove text found between certain tags:  <!-- Comments --!>, <style </style>, <script .. </script>, and <noscript .. </noscript>.  When searching for tags, do not require the close > to immediately follow the tag name. (eg <script type="text/javascript">)  Use Pos('</script,str) followed by PosEx().  Also, using Pos() enforces Case.  So use a case insensitive search, or search on a lowercase copy of your string.

Comment: @GuyGordon, this is not a general-purpose parsing routine for html! There are no HTML comments and no code sections in the html snippet the OP needs to parse.