# Delete all instance of variable substring between tags in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm extracting readable text from HTML into a string and I need to remove the existing text between the `<!--` and the `-->` tags. What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Right now I'm doing it this way:

```
function RemoveIEScripts(const s: string): string;
var
  i: Integer;
  InTag: Boolean;
begin
   Result := '';
   InTag := False;
   for i := 1 to Length(s)-3 do
   begin
      if (s[i] = '<') and (s[i+1] = '!') and (s[i+2] = '-') then
         inTag := True
      else if (s[i] = '-') and (s[i+1] = '-') and (s[i+2] = '>') then
             inTag := False
           else if not InTag then
      Result := Result + s[i];
   end;
end;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try these questions [How to extract text from such type of html source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717405/how-to-extract-text-from-such-type-of-html-source), [Delphi extract string between to 2 tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603982/delphi-extract-string-between-to-2-tags)

Comment: Extracting text from HTML, leaving out the content of the HTML tags is trivial and it's already done. My problem is that occasionally some webpages have small scripting like: <!--[if !IE]> This has been served from cache <![endif]--> and regular parsing won't leave them out. I know I could re-parse looking for <!-- and --> sequences before applying regular HTML stripping but I'm sure this is not the most efficient way to leave these scripts out.

Comment: To do this well you'll want an HTML parser

Comment: Miguel, anything you have that extracts readable text from HTML should *already* strip comments because they never contain readable text. Why should you need a separate pass to get rid of comments? Any HTML parser will do that automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function RemoveIEScripts(const s: string): string; 
var 
  I, J: Integer; 
begin 
  Result := s; 
  I := 1;
  repeat
    I := PosEx('<!--', Result, I);
    if I = 0 then Break;
    J := PosEx('-->', Result, I+4); // 4 = Length('<!--')
    if J = 0 then Break;
    Delete(Result, I, (J+3)-I); // 3 = Length('-->')
  until False;
end;
```