# Search for a string of variable length that has constant begin and end characters

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete all instance of variable substring between tags in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550046/delete-all-instance-of-variable-substring-between-tags-in-delphi)

This is probably a very basic thing but for some reason I just can't figure it out. I need to search a rich text edit for strings that begin with constant first and last characters. The documents use:

```
<sometextofvariablelength>
```

as wild cards for a dynamic search and replace function. Right before the document prints I need to do a quick parse of the text and remove anything wrapped in <> that is still left on the document.

To clear up what I actually need help on. I need to know how to search for a specific character, in this case a '<' and look for the very next '>' and delete that entire string.

UPDATE: Using the suggetsed answer of:

```
function ClearWildCards(const s: string): string;
var
    I, J: integer;
begin
    Result := s;
    I := 1;
    repeat
        I := PosEx('<', Result, I);
        if I = 0 then
            Break;
        J := PosEx('>', Result, I + 4);
        if J = 0 then
            Break;
        Delete(Result, I, (J + 3) - I);
    until False;
end;
```

and then

```
DocPreview.Text := ClearWildCards(DocPreview.Text);
```

Does indeed clear the Wildcards as I need, but it produces another issue. The document loses all of its formatting.

Comment: The answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550046/delete-all-instance-of-variable-substring-between-tags-in-delphi) question can help you.

Comment: That does indeed do what I was needing. However it presents a second issues. I will update the question with the info

Comment: Your translation of the code is wrong, the line `J := PosEx('>', Result, I + 4)` must be `J := PosEx('>', Result, I + 1)` and the line `Delete(Result, I, (J + 3) - I);` must be `Delete(Result, I, (J + 1) - I);`

Comment: Voting to reopen. There is a very interesting issue here. Read the last paragraph of the OP's question. How to manipulate the text in a RICHEDIT control behind the scenes, without altering the formatting, as far as reasonable.

Comment: @JamesW: The *reason* why the formatting is lost is pretty obvious, since the `Text` property contains only the (plain-text) text as a string. When you do `RichEdit1.Text := `, you give the control a completely new document, specified by its plain-text contents.